How to prove the correctness of a sorting program using Hoare logic?
I am working on a problem where I need to analyze a small sorting program using Hoare logic to formally verify its correctness. Here's the program:
if (x < y) {
    u1 = x;
    u2 = y;
} else {
    u1 = y;
    u2 = x;
}

Problem Description:
The intention of the program is that we start with the value of x and y and that the variables u_1 and u_2 are x and y sorted in ascending order. Enter applicable pre-conditions and post-conditions for the program. Then prove with Hoare logic that the program is correct. State all proof obligations and justify that they are correct.
You should note that the postcondition should be such that we know that the initial values ​​of both x and y occur in the set {u1, u2}.
A hunch of how we should tackle the problem

For our precondition, we know that x and y are integers with known values. We don't know, however, if x < y or x > y.
After the program is executed, we should know as our postcondition which integer our output variables u2 and u1 will take on, x or y, as well as u2 ≥ u1 (satisfying the sorted order).

Where I am lost
Where they lose me is:

"You should note that the postcondition should be such that we know that the initial values ​​of both x and y occur in the set {u1, u2}."

If I think it means what it means, then it seems kind of redundant to say that the values are preserved s.t. {u1, u2} = {x, y}, and what the significance of doing this is, in the grand scheme of things. To prove that the program does what it says on the tin? Namely to sort, and not alter it? Is this part of logic necessary to understand to guarantee the data integrity in safety-criticla systems like financial data when creating a program?

"State all proof obligations and justify that they are correct."

I am not exactly sure how this is achieved. For example we've gone through something called "Hoare Triple", where if the precondition P is true before executing the program C, and C terminates, then postcondition Q will be true afterward. Now that we've conditions like if-else, then we'd need to ensure that each branch independently satisfies the postcondition Q?

If branch: (|P $\wedge$ Condition|)$C_1$(|Q|)
Else branch: (|P $\wedge$ $\neg$ Condition|)$C_2$(|Q|)

Other than that, I am not sure how to continue from here. Appreciate any help!
